# Redirect folder to another with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a problem with redirecting folder to a new one. I don't want to use php header() or something similar, i want to achieve this effect with mod_rewrite module and .htaccess file.

The thing I'm trying to do is to redirect the http://domain.com/test/ address to http://domain.com/new/. It's not rewriting, it has to just move the user from old to new address. I was trying to use:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) new/$1
```

But it throws 404 error cause catalog test does not exists. 
How can i redirect the user without creating another folder?

Comment: Kamil do you want the user to see on the browser `domain.com/test` while seeing the content of `domain.com/new`? Or `domain.com/test` does not exist and you want to redirect it to `domain.com/new`?

Comment: @Prix yeah, the second one, I want the user to go to `domain.com/test` and redirect him to `domain.com/new`

Comment: Then @anubhava's answer will work just fine for that. **Are you using Joomla or WordPress or some shop code like opencart, magento, what's the name or do you have any other rules there?**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use external redirect:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /new/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

If you don't want external redirect (no change of URL in browser) then remove `R` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /new/$1 [L,NC]
```

**PS:** Please elaborate: `It's not rewriting, it has to just move the user from old to new address`

Comment: I've put the .htaccess in root directory, copied the code and it's not working (of course applied some changes in folder names). Maybe I should put the .htaccess somewhere else?

Comment: okay, it's working, it was my fault, i was trying without the `/` at the end of the url

Comment: This only redirects `test/`, not `test` (without the forward slash)

Comment: @MarkTickner: You can use: `RewriteRule ^test(/.*)?$ /new$1 [L,NC,R=302]`

Comment: @anubhava sir, I know it's not good way to redirect anyone to solve the issues. but trust me I tried from my side. I am trying to solve this issue from last 7 days but still not working. Can you help me with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64394594/how-to-add-multiple-name-in-the-url