# How to use Apache .htaccess to redirect to another folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect from an old folder to a new one.

I want to redirect the http://domain.com/old/* urls to http://domain.com/new/*.

I found a question which does exactly that:  [Redirect folder to another with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998608/redirect-folder-to-another-with-htaccess)

I've tried writing a .htaccess in the document root with only the following code given in the answer to the above question:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/old/(.*)$ /new/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

I've also enabled mod_rewrite in the httpd.conf file. But I still can't get apache to redirect from the old folder to the new folder.

I've also check the apache error logs, and all I get is the following error:

```
[error] [client x.x.x.x] File does not exist: <documentroot>/old
```

Comment: `^/old/(.*)$` should be `^old/(.*)$`

Comment: @hjpotter92 I tried that, but still getting the same error

Comment: @hjpotter92: The rewrite directive wasn't working, since the AllowOverwrite directive was set to None. Setting it to All, put the directive in effective.

Answer (score 0):

I would skip using `med_rewrite` for this and instead use [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect), if you want everything requested from `old` to be directed to `new`.

```
<Directory />
    Redirect permanent /old /new
</Directory>
```

You could skip `permanent` (Specifies redirect code) depending on your needs. To be able to use a local URL you however need to run Apache >= 2.2.6.