# .htaccess redirect to another folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I currently am working on a project, whereby a redirect is required. However I am having issues with the redirect in the .htaccess file. I have a url which is

```
 http://mylocalapp.local
```

which has a root directory of

```
 /Users/accountname/mylocalapp
```

However I need to put in a redirect of /advice which will be using the root /Users/accountname/advice (example: http://mylocalapp.local/advice)

Here is the redirect in my .htaccess

```
 RewriteRule ^advice/(.*)$ /Users/accountname/advice/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

When I put the url of http://mylocalapp.local/advice , I get a 404 error.

Comment: You can't redirect to a path outside the `document root`. You need to put your `advice` folder inside mylocalapp dir. You man need to look at Alias. [Files Outside the DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html#outside)

Comment: It would be easier to debug the problem if you posted the entire contents of your .htaccess file, but have you turned the RewriteEngine on and specified the RewriteBase? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998608/redirect-folder-to-another-with-htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove that (.*/+)$ expression from the rule.
If that won't work, goto apache>config> httpd , then find Override none, change it to Override All (Thats it)