# Replace part of a URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I had to change the name of a subpage and now the problem is that all shared links on Facebook, Twitter, etc. are not working anymore.

That's why I am trying to redirect only a part of a URL with `.htaccess` but I have no solution yet.

It should work like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/feeds/details/ --> www.mydomain.com/highlights/details/
```

I hope you can help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect folder to another with htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998608/redirect-folder-to-another-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will depend on your server but you are looking for something along these lines

```
    //Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 /feeds(.*) /highlights/$1
```

Comment: In my case it goes from: example.com/folder/file to example.com/folderfile ... removing the slash.

Comment: In my case is adding an extra /

RedirectMatch 301 /states/(.*) /jobs/$1

turns /states/florida ---->  /jobs//florida

Answer (score 3):

You can try rewriting the URL using `RewriteRule`, like follows:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/feeds/details$ /highlights/details/
```

Hope, that works for you.

You can find more information [here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules).

Answer (score 1):

I took your tip and adjusted my reality.

My problem:

```
https://example.com/contact/example.com
```

My solution:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)/example.com(.*) $1/$2
```

After solution, redirect:

```
https://example.com/contact/
```