# How to add multiple name in the URL?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a "know more" button on my website and when the use click on `know more` button then I have to redirect to `product.php` page. Below is the code which i am using and it's working.

```
<a href="product">Know More</a>
```

Now I have to rewrite the URL from `http://example.com/product.php` to

```
http://example.com/products/products2/products3/products
```

I tried below code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^products/products2/products3/products$ product.php [L]
```

but it's not working.

I tried this also

```
RewriteRule ^products/products2/products3/products product.php
```

What can I try next?

Comment: The ```^``` character signifies that something starts with the aforementioned pattern. I am not an expert in rewrite rules, but have you tried ```RewriteRule ^/products product.php```?

Comment: @NotAnerd, I tested your rule here but it's not working. I am getting error "Oops, looks like the page is lost." I am using hostinger hosting.

Comment: `href="product"`? thats not even in the rewrite

Comment: ^^^ That is true, it would be ```product.php```. This may be why your page is *lost*.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, But I used some htaccess code to remove the php from the URL.

Comment: @NotAnerd, No, I just added you code in htaccess and hit the URL like http://example.com/products/products2/products3/products

Comment: @LawrenceCherone , I tested here my code https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=69292ba9-f368-4284-8445-b35f8ff138f4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

# match specific URI
RewriteRule ^products/products2/products3/products/?$ product.php [L,NC]

# php estension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Note changed order of your rules and checking for presence of `.php` file before adding `.php` in front of a URI.

Comment: sir, Give me sometime to check your answer.

Comment: Yes, after adding your answer in the htaccess, I used direct url http://example.com/products/products2/products3/products and  It's working.

Comment: I need to know from where you learn the htacces rules? I have to understand the answer.  I was getting the issue from last 10 days and you solved it within 5 min. Appriciate you help.

Comment: Also I need to know, I have to use <a href="product">Know More</a> or <a href="products/products2/products3/products">Know More</a> on my webpage?

Comment: You can use either of those 2 `href` links on your web page as per your requirement. Both will be served by `product.php` file. I learnt rule rewrite etc  from older answers on Stackexchange sites.

Comment: If I try <a href="product">Know More</a> or <a href="product.php">Know More</a> and clicking on know more button then it's redirecing on product.php page

Comment: Both of these rules don't redirect only rewrite. If `product` is a real directory then use `<a href="product/">`. Moreover completely clear your browser cache.

Comment: I have all the files on my root folder. I don't have any directory. Do I need to use redirect code?

Comment: No need to change any code. What happens when you visit `example.com/product` in browser?

Comment: I am getting "Object not found!" then I tried example.com/product.php and it's displaying my page. but I added htaccess rules which you suggested to change the URL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223191/discussion-between-anubhava-and-user9437856).