# Where RewriteBase value goes?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server

I'm gonna take a code from this answer:
[Redirect folder to another with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998608/redirect-folder-to-another-with-htaccess/18998868#18998868)

So, I'd like to know where **RewriteBase** goes for real?! According to the smart guy from the linked answer it goes to the first part of the **RewriteRule**. So the second part requires a slash ("/")

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /new/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

I don't remember where, but I read somewhere that it goes to the second part. And in fact my .htaccess is written in accordance with this rule. So, my rewrite rules looks this way

```
RewriteRule ^script$ folder/some_script [L,NC,R=302]
```

And actually it works for me. But now I read the linked answer because I need something other and I'm confused. I have no idea if this affects performance much, I just want to do it right. And I want to know "where it goes for real", to the first part, to the second, or to the both? Now I need a redirect from the folder+script to another folder+script. So how it should be?

```
#v1
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/folder/some_script$ other_folder/some_other_script [L,NC,R=302]
```

⠀

```
#v2
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder/some_script$ /other_folder/some_other_script [L,NC,R=302]
```

⠀

```
#v3
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/folder/some_script$ /other_folder/some_other_script [L,NC,R=302]⠀
```

⠀

```
#v4
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder/some_script$ other_folder/some_other_script [L,NC,R=302]⠀
```

I'd like to clarify that "yes", I need a redirect to another folder and which has a script with different name, so I don't need this "$1". One more thing **please, don't guess, don't answer if you don't know that for sure**. I can guess a lot of things too, I can test if this is work. I know that when I put the slash to the second part, it works, and if you don't put it also works. I mean:

```
RewriteBase /
# this works for me correctly
RewriteRule ^some_script$ folder/some_script [L,NC,R=302]

# this also works for me correctly, but I use the first way
# RewriteRule ^script$ /folder/some_script [L,NC,R=302]
```

I want to know how it's right! And I want to know how to do it right with a redirect from a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the target (the second argument) of a RewriteRule is relative, then the value of `RewriteBase` is prepended to it.

So, let's take `RewriteBase /some/path/` as example.

- `RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar`: RewriteBase doesn't apply since the target (`/bar`) is absolute
- `RewriteRule ^foo$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/bar`: same because it is an HTTP redirect to an URL, still not a relative path
- `RewriteRule ^foo$ bar`: `RewriteBase` applies since `bar` is relative so the request `/foo` will be rewritten to `/some/path/bar`

But, wait, it also works without an explicit `RewriteBase`? Yes, it **can**: Apache is able to "guess" the path to prepend by default to a relative target but there is some cases where Apache isn't able to correctly guess it (when an `Alias` comes to play or the use of `VirtualDocumentRoot`, `UserDir` for examples)

In case of a redirect (R=30[12]) with a relative path (instead of an URL), Apache works the same: it will just then prepend the `ServerName` and appropriate scheme on top of it.

Note:

> RewriteRule ^/folder/some_script$ ...

In a directory context, like a .htaccess file, this kind of rule will never match because of the `^/` since Apache truncates the path to remove the part of the path corresponding to this context including its last `/` (eg: if the path of the URL is `/foo`, the path tested by `RewriteRule` in a .htaccess file located at the DocumentRoot is only `foo`, not the string `/foo`).

Comment: You know what @julp, you actually explained that very well. And now I understand why the target with a slash and without works for me. And also I realize that I should probably use a slash (in my case, for a target) because then Apache can relax a bit and apply nothing, right. So, I know that SO don't want me to say "thank you", but still thanks for chewing it up and putting it in my head!

Comment: Hm... @julp Can't vote up your answer, system won't let me. Not enough reputation... But you still know 1+

Comment: Not a big deal, I'm glad if I was able to answer your concerns ;)